# The method apply() is undefined for the type SharedPreferences.Editor

Tags: java, android

code: http://pastebin.com/sh5TKhVv
I have coppied this code from book and I did not change anything but it have this error in lines 96 and 192.

```
preferencesEditor.apply(); --> The method apply() is undefined for the type SharedPreferences.Editor
```

Answer (score 1):

[SharedPreferences.Editor.apply();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply%28%29)  is added in **API LEVEL 9** .if you are using lower version from 9 then use [SharedPreferences.Editor. commit()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit%28%29) to save all chnages with  SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

```
shared_preferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
editor =shared_preferences.edit();
editor.putString("test","Done");
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem although I'm using API LEVEL 17.
 This line solved the problem for me:

`SharedPreferences.Editor.commit();`